# How to search more character string into smaller string through sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have a inventory table where all the items are present with unique ID such as S0001,S0002,T0001,T0002,.. etc. with their respective costs.

```
Inventory Table --
ItemID Cost
S0001 5.5
S0002 2.5
T0001 2.5
T0002 1.5
```

Now lets say i create an invoice where some one buys S0001, so the value saved inside the table for that invoice is S0001(shirt) and if someone buys S0002, it will be S0002(shirt).

```
Invoice Table
InvId ItemName  quantity
1   shirt(S0001)  1.5
2   shirt(S0002)  1.3
```

I want to retrieve the cost price of items from inventory data base for each item in already created invoices. Instead of getting the unique ID of item, i get the UniqueID(description) eg. S0001(shirt) from invoice database.

How do i query the cost price(present in inventory) of Item name obtained from invoice database in inventory database.My search string which is from Invoice table have more characters then my search into string which has less characters.
My goal is to retrieve cost of S0001(shirt) from inventory table which is going to be 5.5.

Note: Unfortunatly I cannot change the structure of any tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL, you can do something like this

```
 SELECT * FROM tblInvoice INNER JOIN tblInventory ON
 ( LEFT(ItemName, LOCATE("(", ItemName) - 1) = ItemId )
```

Updated query to  work with question changed:

```
 SELECT * FROM tblInvoice INNER JOIN tblInventory ON
 ( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTR(ItemName, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(ItemName) - 1), "(",  -1) = ItemId )
```

Comment: For sql server, just change `locate` to `charindex` and double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: Can i also look for last '(' or ')' as its below is also a possibility<br/>
Shirt(S0001)<br/>
Shirt(peterEngland)(S0001)<br/>
So if i can fine last ')' ...it solves my problem.
P.S I also edited the question

Comment: So there is no general format of the itemid inside your itemname. @A.Learn

Comment: There can be any character but at the end there is going to be (itemId)...For example XXXXXXX(S0001)
It was my mistake when i posted the original question i corrected it before my last comment.My apologies to you.

Comment: @A.Learn, but there is a way to do. It is a little bit long. So take me sometimes to write it down.

Comment: I tested the query it works but give multiple rows(number of rows of inventory) each containing the same cost value.

Comment: Can you explain me why did you use Join. It also worked with below query which i created.
SELECT cost FROM pftcg_inventory WHERE ( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTR(ii.title, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(ii.title) - 1), "(", -1) = sku 

'ii' is the alias for pftcg_invoice_item table. and sku is ItemID present in inventory. With above query it only returns one row and with Join it returns multiple rows.